# How to split a string on every 25th line break(\n) if it contains multiple \n

Tags: c++, string, split

I've read a file and stored its content into a `std::string` variable `BUF` and now want to split the data into small blocks where each block would contain 25 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it!

```
    if(N>25) \\N no of lines
     {
         int i=0;
         std::istringstream ss(text);
         text="";
         string splited,part="";
         while(std::getline(ss, splited, '\n')) {
              part+=splited+"\n";
              if(i==24)
              {
                i=0;
                part.erase(part.size() - 1);
                d.Insert(part,time);
                cout<<part;
                part="";
                continue;
              }
              else{
              ++i;
              continue;
              }
           }
           if(i!=0)
              {
                 d.Insert(part,time);
              }
     }
else{
        d.Insert(text,time);
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two options:

- construct `std::istringstream` from `BUF` (or use the stream with which you read the file) and use `std::getline` to read line by line and append to previous lines, while counting up to 25 and so on...
- use `std::string::find` in a loop counting to 25 and then use `std::string::substr` or `std::find` and construction from an iterator range.

I think that's sufficient hint.

Comment: Simply keep iterator/index to position where you've left + 2. That will be the start of the next chunk.